# Prove a group using cayley table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, cayley-table

there is an example that my lecturer went through which is to prove (Z3,+)is a group. He prove this using a cayley table. I am stuck at the part when he mentioned:

[0]+[2]=2

[1]+[2]=[3]=[0]

and also when he prove that it satisfy the inverse, he wrote down[0]*-1=[0] and [1]*-1=[2]. I am not to sure how he get this result from the table. Thank you!

Comment: You can write the multiplicative cayley table.

Comment: What does it mean to *prove a group*? Maybe your instructor wanted to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z}),+)$ is a *cyclic* group by filling the Cayley table, but one does not need to that to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z}),+)$ *is a group*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think he is trying to use this example to demonstrate the use of cayley table. But i don't still don't get how it is done for the example i am stated above on [1]+[2]=[3]=[0].

Comment: @JaySun: well, $1+2=3$ and $[3]=[0]$ by the definition of (the elements) of $\mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: i understand that 1+2=3, but how is it equals to [0] back again, this is the part which confuse me. Thank you.

Comment: There is no 3.  [1] = {all itegers with remainder 1 when divided by 3}={.....-2,1,4,7.....}.  [2]={all integers with remainder 2} = {...-1,2,5,8....}.  And [0[]={all integers with remainder 0} = {...,-3,0,3,6,9...}.  So [1]+[2] = {all sums of integers with remainders 1 added to integer with remainder 2} = {all multiples of 3} ={all integers with remainder 0} = [0].

Comment: ...or... consider $Z_7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  What is $3 + 6$?  $3+6 = 9$.  $9$ is not acceptable.  So we must "circle back" and reduce by $7$ and take the remainder to get .... $[3]+[6] = [9] = [9-2] = [2]$.  So the same thing in $Z_3$.  $[1] + [2] = [3] = [3-3] = [0]$. ....or....

Comment: ....or..... [0] = 3k + 0.  [1] = 3j + 1.  [2] = 3m + 2.  So [1]+[2] = 3j + 1 + 3m + 2 = 3j + 3m + 3 = 3(j+m+1) + 0 = [0]

Comment: ... in short... $\mathbb Z/(k\mathbb Z)$ is the set where you cycle around.  As soon as you get to $k$ you "jump" back to zero.  [0] = [k] = [2k] = [3k]=......  so [3] = [0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cayley table of $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
+ & [0] & [1] & [2]\\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
\hline
[1] & [1] & [2] & [0]\\
\hline
[2] & [2] & [0] & [1]\\
\end{array}

and recall that within this group, the binary operation between elements is defined as:
$$(\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}): \qquad a+b := (a+b) \text{ mod }3$$
which explains why in the table we see things like $[2]+[2]$, which traditionally you would imagine is $[4]$, but in this case we have $4 \text{ mod }3 \equiv 1$, hence $[2]+[2]=[1]$.

Going a bit deeper assuming you know what an equivalent class is, the reason we've been putting brackets around everything is because *additional modulo 3 is an equivalence relation* and things like $[4]=[1]$ and $[234]=[0]$ are valid in this group because they're *equivalent*, that is, of the same class. An important thing to know is that addition in this group is a *well-defined operation*, meaning that since we have $[4]=[1]$ and $[234]=[0]$  (that is, $4 \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 3$ and $234 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 3$) that the following should be true:
$$[4]+[234]=[1]+[0].$$

Comment: Thank you for explain everything in detail. really appreciate your time in explaining this to me. I have now understand the concept behind this. thank You

Comment: @JaySun Glad to help! If you need any clarification just leave another comment :)